# PHP Json decode object exist

Tags: php, json, foreach, decode

how can i get all "steamids" from Players where "gameid" exist and have the value "730"?
it Shows:
 NOTICE Undefined property: stdClass::$gameid on line number 31 
because "gameid" doesnt exist in every element

Code:

```
$players = json_decode(file_get_contents("test.json"));
foreach($players->response->Players as $mydata)
{
if($players->gameid == "730"){
echo $mydata->steamid . "\n";
}

}
```

My json:

```
{
    "response": {
        "players": [
            {
                "steamid": "76561198273176399",
                "loccountrycode": "US"
            },
            {
                "steamid": "76561198386141115",
                "gameid": "730",
                "loccountrycode": "DE"
            },
            {
                "steamid": "76561198019025166",
                "gameid": "730",
                "loccountrycode": "RU"
            },
            {
                "steamid": "76561198010529217",
                "loccountrycode": "DK"
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

Thanks a lot. With best regards.

Comment: start `players` with small letter in foreach and `if($mydata->gameid`

Comment: @splash58  
  
thanks, but it Shows me: NOTICE Undefined property: stdClass::$gameid on line number 31 because "gameid" doesnt exist in every element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
$players->response->Players
if($players->gameid == "730"){
```

To

```
$players->response->players // small letter "p"
if($mydata->gameid == "730"){
```

It's the same as `$mydata->steamid`

Since not every player has a `gameid` it's better to check on that aswell:

```
if( isset($mydata->gameid) && $mydata->gameid === '730' ) // or check on empty if the "gameid" can be set but also can be empty
```

Comment: thanks, but it Shows me: NOTICE Undefined property: stdClass::$gameid on line number 31 because "gameid" doesnt exist in every element

Comment: Updated the answer